# Can I use same Instrumental variable for two of my endogenous variables?

Tags: instrumental-variables, endogeneity, 2sls

I have the following model :
y= X1+x2+X1*X2+ other control
both X1 and X2  are endogenous. Can I use the same instrument for both X1 and X2?

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to have at least as many *different* instruments as there are endogenous regressors.

If we rewrite the equation as $Y = X_1 +  X_2 + X_3$, where $X_3 = X_1X_2$, it is evident that we need three instruments. If you already had two instruments in mind $-$ $Z_1$ as an instrument for $X_1$ and $Z_2$ as an instrument for $X_2$ $-$ it would be natural to define a third instrument for the interaction as $Z_3 = Z_1Z_2$.

However, note that even though your theory for why these are sutiable instruments might suggest that $Z_1$ is an instrument for $X_1$ only, technically, $Z_1$, $Z_2$, and $Z_3$ are all used as instruments for $X_1$. And $X_2$. And $X_3$.

In this sense: Yes, you **have to** use the same instruments for both $X_1$ and $X_2$ (and $X_1X_2$). But the answer is no in the sense that you must have at least two unique instruments (three, counting their interaction).

See also [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/68278/264076) and in particular the link in it to the [Mostly Harmless blog](https://www.mostlyharmlesseconometrics.com/2010/02/multiple-endogenous-variables-what-now/) on why it would be good to avoid this type of specification if possible.

> "Models with multiple endogenous variables are indeed hard to identify and the results can be hard to interpret. So we don’t usually like to see them – for one thing it’s not clear why you’re tackling two causal questions at the same time; one is hard enough. [...] More generally, it doesn’t make sense to think of one endogenous variable as a “control” when looking at the effects of another, at least not a good one (in the sense in which we use the terms good and bad control in chapter 3).  So any time someone shows me a problem with more than one endogenous variable, my first question is always: why?